# My app alert "app has stopped" if is started without internet connection

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an app using phonegap and the network-information plugin to check if the app is connected to internet to pull some data from the internet. Everything works fine if I start the app conencted to internet, but if I start the app without any internet connection it just alerts "Droog(name of the app)" has stopped. I actually have no idea how can I debug or trace this error.

JS Portion:

```
      if((navigator.connection.type).toUpperCase() != "NONE" && (navigator.connection.type).toUpperCase() != "UNKNOWN") {
        // check for updates every time the app initialize
        this.verificarFechas();
        // if device is offline and get back online
        document.addEventListener('online', this.verificarFechas, false);
      }else{
        alert('Esta aplicación funciona mejor conectada a internet. Porfavor revisa tu conexión.');
      }
```

config.xml:

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager"/>
</feature>
```

Let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: Have you tried something other than `alert()` in the `else`?

Comment: I'm facing this for few days. I think it's a bug in network plugin. Same code worked before, but it stopped working after I used new version of network plugin. Not sure though.

Comment: may be function callback for 'offline' event missing ? i.e.document.addEventListener('offline',"blabla" ,false); !

Comment: @AtanuCSE same happened to me when removed and installed the plugin again :/.

jeekonline well the documentation says that event is used when the device is online and goes offlinen but im going to give it a try and tell you